# Bootstrap - Align 2 images on save row with size adaptation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put 2 images on the same row, with size adaptation when I increase/decrease the page size, without have the image move to the other row.

Currently when my page is sized down, my second image (black block on the description) moves to the other row

Here is an screenshot of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

**CSS:**

```css
.album {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.album img {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**And my html part:**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="album">
       <img src="images/album2017.png">
       <img src="images/album2016.png">
   </div>
```

I hope you can help me,
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `sm` breakpoint [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/669/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's should work

```
  .album {
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }

    .album img {
         width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.album {
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
height:auto;
width:auto;

}

.album img {
padding: 10px;
width:50%;
height :auto;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for. Adjust your width % to scale according to your screen size / block size

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o89xpue6/)